# Send email to user when I publish a new post

Tags: posts, actions, publish

i want to send email only new post publish in wordpress admin

when i pulish anything its sending mail to user how to restric this to only new post added to send mail to user

```
  function wpse_19040_notify_admin_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $new_status !== 'publish' || $old_status === 'publish' )
        return;
    if ( ! $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type ) )
        return;

    global $wpdb;
    $newsletterdata = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."newsletter");    
    foreach ( $newsletterdata as $newsletteremailall ) 
    {   
        $newsletteremailall = $newsletteremailall->email;   
         if(filter_var($newsletteremailall, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
         {    
          $subject = $post->post_title;
          $message = 'Our new post is here '."\n".'Post Title: ' .$post->post_title. "\n"."click here to visit post: " . get_permalink( $post->ID );
          wp_mail( $newsletteremailall, $subject, $message );    
          } 
          else 
          {
              
          }          
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_19040_notify_admin_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updated code for statuses as per @Fredrik's answer as his is more accurate.

---

To trigger this when publishing, you could change your first if to

```
if ( $new_status === 'inherit' && $old_status === 'new' )
```

That way, your code should trigger only when you publish a post.

EDIT:

Some notes on your code.

```
if ( ! $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type ) )
```

this will do nothing, as it's an assignment for a variable. It means, that you will get the current post type, and assign it to `$post_type` and it will always pass.

What I think you're trying to achieve, is for this to work only for a specific post type. If that's the case, change this line to:

```
if ( 'my_custom_post_type' !== get_post_type_object( $post->post_type ) )
```

where `my_custom_post_type` should be the post type for which you wish to send emails for.

For this line:

```
$newsletteremailall = $newsletteremailall->email;
```

It's a bad practice to overwrite the initial variable. Maybe name it `$email` instead of `$newsletteremailall`, because you may need it later, but you will no longer have access to it.

Comment: Okey i will change it thanks @Petar Petrov sir

Comment: No problem @jykmhar123. If this answer helped answer your question, please mark it as such. If you have anymore questions, feel free to comment here :)

Comment: When I move post to trash its sending me mail

Comment: Yes, that was the issue I mentioned. I've updated my answer to use @Fredrik's statuses, as I was not aware of the `new` status in combination with `inherit`. If possible, you could flag his answer as the better one.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the first if like this, it will ONLY send you these mails when you have created a NEW post. Not when you change it between different status. And this goes for all post types, you might (as mentioned before) look at the $post_type and change that to your custom post type, otherwise this is fired regardless of post type.

```
      function wpse_19040_notify_admin_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
        if ( $old_status === 'new' && $new_status === 'inherit' )
    
        if ( ! $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type ) )
            return;
    
        global $wpdb;
        $newsletterdata = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."newsletter");    
        foreach ( $newsletterdata as $newsletteremailall ) 
        {   
            $newsletteremailall = $newsletteremailall->email;   
             if(filter_var($newsletteremailall, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
             {    
              $subject = $post->post_title;
              $message = 'Our new post is here '."\n".'Post Title: ' .$post->post_title. "\n"."click here to visit post: " . get_permalink( $post->ID );
              wp_mail( $newsletteremailall, $subject, $message );    
              } 
              else 
              {
                  
              }          
        }
    }
    add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_19040_notify_admin_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```